# How to show python virtual env with a shorten Powershell prompt?

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I use the following script to shorten the Powershell prompt

```
function prompt {'PS ' + $(Get-Location | Split-Path -Leaf) + "> "}
```

It does the job but it does not show the activated python virtual environment.

How can I have the virtual environment prepended to the prompt? for example:

```
(venv) PS Document>
```

Thank you.